# Inheritance in C++ ,How to call specific function from class

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In this program How to access specific function in there child class.

```
Class A
{
  Private:
  Int variables,....;
  Protected:
  Void funA{

                      };
Void funB{

                      };

Void funC{

                      };
};

Class B :public class A
{
   funC();///Here I want to access only function funC() and FunA() & FunB() should not access..
};
```

Now in class C all functions of class A should access..

```
Class C :public class A
{
funA();
funB();
funC();. //// All functions should be Access..
};
```

How can I do that.....

Comment: C++ is case-sensitive. The keywords `class`, `void`, `int`, `private`, and `protected` must be all lowercase. `FunA` is a different thing from `funA`.

Comment: I know,It is not perfect code,It's only Reference....

Comment: Did you try it? What is your actual problem? Do you get errors?

Comment: @user13734955 Unfortunately we code posted by people of all abilities, and the code often contains gross errors. This makes it hard to know what is merely 'imperfect code' and what are genuine errors. If you want your question to get the best possible answers please take the trouble to post accurate code.

Comment: it makes no sense to directly call funC from class B; either the function has to be static or you need an object or another inheritance hierarchy

Comment: Are you trying to say that, given an object `B obj` you want to be able to call `obj.funC()`, but not be able to call `obj.funA()` and `obj.funB()`? (I.e. you want to violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?) The code currently conveys something different, that you want to call `funC()` from within the definition of `B` (which does not make sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have those three classes, you can use the `friend` keyword to mark class C to have access to private and protected members from class A.

```
class A
{
public:
    void FunC() {};

private:
    friend class C;

    void FunA() {};
    void FunB() {};
};

class B : A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        FunC();
    }
};

class C : A
{
public:
    C()
    {
        FunA();
        FunB();
        FunC();
    }
};
```

You can check this page out for more detailed information:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/